# How do I register for captcha v3 for chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, recaptcha-v3

I was trying to integrate google captcha v3 for my chrome extension. However I see that domain name is mandatory to register for captcha v3. Any thoughts on what should be put in the Domains list field for chrome extension as shown in the screenshot below?

[image: Captcha v3 admin console]

Comment: Here's an answer that specifies putting the extension ID as the allowed domain but there is no citation of source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56332614/387187

I'll try to circle back if I learn anything through testing

Answer (score 0):

Get your extension id from chrome://extensions

*ID: eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh*
(displays when developer mode is turned on)

Use the extension id as-is in the reCAPTCHA config as an additional domain and save.

Also, make sure you've updated your content_security_policy in manifest.json to allow https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/ https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/

I've confirmed this works for chrome extensions. Without it I get
*@firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error)
from the App Check exchange endpoint (https://content-firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/)